# fetch data should be store in a state

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, reactjs

fetching data from mysql but unable to store that data in a state. I'm building user live location. users data is located in mysql and im fetching that data and trying to show data in  google map.

```
import { React, useState, useEffect } from "react";
    import "./App.css";
    import axios from "axios";
    import {
      GoogleMap,
      withScriptjs,
      withGoogleMap,
      Marker,
      InfoWindow,
    } from "react-google-maps";
    
    function Map() {
      const [selectedPark, setSelectedPark] = useState([]);
      var data = "";
      var config = {
        method: "get",
        url: "http://localhost:3002/user",
        headers: {},
        data: data,
      };
      useEffect(() => {
        axios(config)
          .then(function (response) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
            setSelectedPark(response.data);
            console.log(selectedPark);
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
          });
      }, []);
      return (
        <GoogleMap
          defaultZoom={10}
          defaultCenter={{ lat: 24.860966, lng: 66.990501 }}
        >
          {selectedPark.map((park) => (
            <Marker
              key={park.user_Id}
              position={{
                lat: park.latitude,
                lng: park.longitude,
              }}
              onClick={() => {
                setSelectedPark(park);
              }}
              onCloseClick={() => {
                setSelectedPark(null);
              }}
              icon={{
                url: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/leighhalliday/google-maps-react-demo/2bcd4ca7184ea9ed9edbc25021c2e721a74c027f/public/skateboarding.svg",
                scaledSize: new window.google.maps.Size(25, 25),
              }}
            />
          ))}
          {selectedPark && (
            <InfoWindow
              position={{
                lat: selectedPark.latitude,
                lng: selectedPark.longitude,
              }}
            >
              <div>
                <h2>{selectedPark.area_name}</h2>
                <p>{selectedPark.area_description}</p>
              </div>
            </InfoWindow>
          )}
        </GoogleMap>
      );
    }
    const WrappedApp = withScriptjs(withGoogleMap(Map));
    function App() {
      return (
        <div style={{ width: "100vw", height: "100vw" }}>
          <WrappedApp
            googleMapURL={`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=geometry,drawing,places&key=AIzaSyDmVpJ44AZEUIs-ml0R1Q0URcmr-Q-DMC4`}
            loadingElement={<div style={{ height: "100%" }} />}
            containerElement={<div style={{ height: "100%" }} />}
            mapElement={<div style={{ height: "100%" }} />}
          />
        </div>
      );
    }
    
    export default App;
```

server is working perfectly, i can see the data from console, it works fine but the only problem is that im unable to store that data in a state

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [useState set method not reflecting change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately)

Comment: no i'm getting a blank array

Comment: Yes, because you're console logging immediately after calling the state updater. That's not how state works.

Comment: @Yusura Masood you won't see the log  immediately after the state update, it is because React batched the setState

Comment: i used console.log after the useEffect and still it shows the blank array

Comment: You need to add a new useffect and run pass the console.log

Answer (score 0):

React batches `setState` , so you can't see the change immediately.
Do this

Add one more `useEffect`

```
useEffect(()=>{
   console.log(selectedPark)
},[selectedPark])
```

Comment: im still getting a blank array

Comment: This is half true. The most important part to note (as linked in the duplicate) is `selectedPark` is a `const`. State or not, a `const` **cannot change**.

Comment: []length: 0[[Prototype]]: Array(0)

Answer (score -1):

```
useEffect(() => {
   const fetchData = async () => {
        axios(config)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(response => setSelectedPark(response.data))
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
   }

   fetchData();
}, []);
```

Try this example of request in useEffect, diff with your code that in my example I return data from promise using promise chain (1st then call json method, 2nd then return clear data and save in state)

For more comfortable debugging you can console.log in a place when you saving your data in a state

Comment: TypeError: response.json is not a function
    at App.js:23

Comment: Try to remove call json method, I'm not sure, but it can be unnecessary with axios